# In CMOS, can I assume the delay of a multiplexer is negligible compared to the delay of an inverter?

Tags: multiplexer, cmos, inverter, delay, asic

Let say I have a ring oscillator, and I modify the ring so that the output of an inverter is connected to an input of a 2-to-1 MUX, and the output of the MUX is connected to the input of the next inverter (see picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDm83.jpg ). Assuming I have an odd number of inverters, this structure allows me to skip some even number of inverters and still have an oscillating output. For example, let say I have 9 inverters and I decide to skip the first 4 inverters. The remaining 5 inverters forms a regular ring oscillator. My question is: Would the frequency of the output produced by this 5-inverter ring oscillator be **significantly differently** from the case where the same 5 inverters are connected directly without any MUX between adjacent inverters?

In other words, in CMOS, can I assume the delay of a multiplexer is negligible compared to the delay of an inverter?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say the mux will have _more_ delay than an inverter, because the mux must have more logic in the signal path - but to be sure, you will have to check the datasheets for the parts you are actually using.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting a device like a mux will have a very significant effect on your ring oscillator.  A noninverting CMOS mux has more than twice the propagation delay of an inverter because the mux itself is inverting.  If you want a noninverting mux, you need to add another inverter.  If you use a mux made with pass transistors, it will increase the capacitive loading on the previous inverter and slow it down.

Bottom line: no such thing as a free lunch!

What are you trying to build, anyway?  A digitally programmable oscillator?

Comment: Yes, I'm building a programmable oscillator. My goal is to measure the frequency of each configuration, then set up a system of linear equations, and then solve for the delay of each inverter. I was hoping that if the delay of the multiplexers is negligible, I can easily deduce the delay of each inverter.

Comment: If all of your inverters are the same, why not just divide the measured oscillation period by the number of inverters?  Is there any reason it needs to be more complicated?

Comment: Actually because of process variation, the delays of the inverters are all slightly different. I want to accurately measure the delay of each inverter so that I can quantify how much is the effect of process variation.

Comment: I don't think the variation within one single ring oscillator will be very significant due to the size (>100 inverters).  It would probably be more effective to build an array of ring oscillators that can capture process variations across a relatively large area.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really make any such assumptions in general.

If you want to know how the delays for a certain kind of multiplexer/inverter combination relate to each other, you have to check their data sheets. What I would expect to find there is that a single inverter is one the simplest kinds of gates, so it probably has the lowest delay - when comparing devices made with the same technology. However, the difference between devices made with different technologies can be so large that normally the choice of technology is probably the largest decisive factor for the delay. For example: at 25C & 5V, a 74HC04 has a typical propagation delay of 7ns, and a 74HC157 has 11-12ns. Decreasing the voltage would increase the delay. By changing to 74LVC technology and decreasing the power supply to 3.3V, you can get a 74LVC04 with a typical delay of 2ns, or a 74LVC157A with a delay of 2.5-2.7ns.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the details of the technology you're using and which "delay" you are talking about in the mux.

Most "mux" implementations require 2 levels of gate, and thus their delay might approximate twice that of an inverter.

In an FPGA, a group of related gates is typically rolled into a single CLB (logic block) with a fixed delay whether you are using it as 1 gate or 4, and thus the inverter and MUX may have the same delay. (It is also likely that the inverter is optimised away or rolled into another CLB making the comparison difficult!)

It is also possible to implement a MUX using pass transistors, effectively transmission switches; these would impose very little delay on the signal, so the inverter has a longer delay. (However the selection logic. turning pass transistors on or off, would have its own delay, probably several levels of gate).

So a mux implemented using 74HC4066 analog switch would have a typical delay of 3 or 4 ns and a turn on/off time of 20-25 ns, for comparison with 7ns (inverter) 11-12ns (mux) from Laszlo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have some control over the speed of a ring oscillator, you should probably add some switchable capacitance and/or current-limiting devices (e.g. a long skinny transistor with a shorter fatter transistor as a configurable bypass), and you should design your circuit at the transistor level.  Logic synthesizers will frequently tweak gate-level designs so as to improve efficiency, in ways which will not increase the maximum propagation time but may reduce the minimum.  For example, a direct implementation of an AND and OR gates would be a NAND or NOR followed by an inverter, suggesting that "(A or not B)" would be realized as "not (A nor not B)"--three gates, with a 3-gate propagation time from B and a two-gate propagation from A.  The same function may be computed with one less gate, however, if the expression is rewritten as "B nand not A".  The time of what had been the faster path will be unchanged (signal A still flows through two gates), but what had been the slower path (signal B) will now flow through one gate rather than B, thus making it the faster path.

While it's almost certainly possible to have a ring oscillator whose frequency is adjustable by varying the number of stages, and there may well be cases where that would be the best approach to having an adjustable-frequency ring oscillator, I would suggest that any such design must be specified in such a fashion as to only have one possible realization.  For example, one might have a NAND gate feeding a sequence of inverters whose input is wired as a "bus" above it, and have pass transistors connecting each even-numbered inverter to that bus, arranging things so that at most one inverter's pass transistors can be enabled at a time.  In that scenario, if one specified that circuit elements must be individually realized as transistors without merging, the effects of varying the length of the signal chain would probably be fairly predictable.